# can some one convert the code below to a function?

Tags: matlab

Can someone please help me write this into a function using MATLAB?

```
for i=1:50
  E(i+1)=E(i)+((W(i)[Sin[α(i)]-Tan[ϕ]Cos[α(i)]/F]-c*l/F))/(Cos[α(i)]+(Tan[ϕ]Sin[α(i)]/F))
end
```

Comment: Yes, someone can. But What kind of function you are looking for?

Comment: I do not understand fully what you are saying. but I meant to say make the above run as a script in matlab. thank you

Comment: Function and Script are two very different structures in matlabyet both stored in `.m` file format. Functions may return values and they **do not** share variables with the parent workspace and may contain nested functions. Scripts **do not** return values, **cannot** contain nested functions and **fully** share variables with the parent workspace. I'm asking what are the inputs, what shall be returned etc.

Comment: Say you want a `FooBar.m`, then provide us what shall be done when one call `FooBar` or `FooBar(inputs)`. Without this information one can only wish you good luck.

Comment: I should have known script and function are different. It just escaped me. The input variable here is 'F'. thank you.

Comment: And what about `alpha(i)`, `phi` and the others?

Comment: these will be determined from another script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the following formula:

```
E = cumsum(((W.*(sin(a)-tan(phi).*cos(a)./F)-c.*l./F))./(cos(a)+(tan(phi).*sin(a)./F)));
```

This way, you don't need a for loop.
You can input `W`, `a`, `phi`, `F`, `c` and `l` as arrays or scalars. All the arrays you put must be the same size.

In your case, I believe that `W` and `a` will be [50x1] arrays while `phi`, `F`, `c` and `l` will be scalars.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it as a script:

```
for ii=1:50
  E(ii+1)=E(ii)+((W(ii)[sin(alpha(ii))-tan(phi)*cos(alpha(ii)]/F)-c*l/F))/(cos{alpha(ii))+(Tan[phi]Sin[alpha(ii)]/F))
end
```

All variables (E(1), W,... **must** be defined in parent workspace.

If you want to run it as a function:

```
function[E]=FooBar(F,alpha)
%% define variables thet are not inputs
E=zeros(50,1);
W=rand(50,1);
phi=rand;
c=rand;
l=rand;

for ii=1:50
  E(ii+1)=E(ii)+((W(ii)*(sin(alpha(ii))-tan(phi)*cos(alpha(ii))/F)-c*l/F))/(cos{alpha(ii))+(tan(phi)*sin(alpha(ii))/F))
end
```

---

**EDIT**
I suggest creating fucntion like that:

```
function[E]=MainFoo()
%% Code for necessary variables...

W=FooW(Winput1,Winput2);
alpha=FooAlpha(AlphaInput1,AlphaInput2);
%% other parameters calculated by Foo*** functions

E=FooE(E1,W,alpha,phi,F,c,l);

%% Nested function
  function[WW]=FooW(Win1,Win2)
    %% code to calculate W
  end
  function[Alpha]=FooAlpha(AlIn1,AlIn2)
  %% code to calculate alpha
  end
%%Other Foo*** functions

  function[OutE]FooE(E0,Ws,Alphs,Phi,FF,cc,ll)
    OutE=zeros(50,1);
    OutE(1)=E0;
    for ii=1:50
      OutE(ii+1)=OutE(ii)+((Ws(ii)*(sin(Alphs(ii))-tan(Phi)*cos(Alphs(ii)]/FF)-cc*ll/FF))/(cos(Alphs(ii))+(tan(Phi)Sin[Alphs(ii)]/FF));
end
  end
end
```